Let $A$ be a set and, for each $a\in A$ let $f_a: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ measurable. Is function $\sup\{f_a(x): a\in A \}$ also measurable?
Let $A$ be a set and, for each $a\in A$ let $f_a: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ measurable. Is function $\sup\{f_a(x): a\in A \}$ also measurable?
enter image description here
and here is my answer, I think it has some mistakes but I don't know how to solve it.
enter image description here

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

I think its best if you read: "How to ask a good question" https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#10992 otherwise your question probably gets downvoted and closed.

Let $g\colon\mathbb R \to (0,+\infty)$ not measurable. For any $a\in\mathbb R$, let $f_a=g(a)\delta_a$ (i.e. $f_a(a)=g(a)$, $0$ elsewhere). $f_a$ is measurable for all $a$, but $\sup f_a = g$, so it is not measurable.
